# CSS Background Image Size is not working when text is empty

Tags: css, background-image

Below is the CSS for a background image I am trying to show.  It is used for a draggable element on my page to show a `Drag handle` for a user to drag items.

My problem is `background-size: 16px 16px;` nor `width: 16px; heith: 16px;` work.

It will show nothing on the page if there is no text inside my `<span>`  I need to figure out how I can make an empty span tag have a width that I set for this background image to show?

http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/Hnyjf

HTML...

```
<div class="tools">

  <span class="handle"></span>

  <a href="#" class="collapse">-</a>

</div>
```

CSS...

```
.handle {
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-image:  
  url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried display: block; on your span? You can add a width on it after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because empty inline elements hasn't any width. You could set your element to an inline-block element:

```
.handle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  This works great.  A side note, I have to make sure I use all 3 of these `width: 16px;` 
`height: 16px;` 
`background-size: 16px 16px;` in my case for it to look correctly